# Listen to shift+key pression in Angularjs with Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I'm trying to detect SHIFT+TAB pression in angularjs. The code below works well in IE 11 and Chrome, but Firefox keeps saying "evt is undefined".
This error appears with the pression of any key in Firefox. How can I solve this?

```
function isShiftTabPressed (event) {
  var keyCode = getKeyCodeFromEvent(event);
  if (listenForShiftKey() && keyCode === 9) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function listenForShiftKey (e) {
  var evt = e || window.event;
  if (evt.shiftKey) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function getKeyCodeFromEvent (event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  return (typeof event.which === 'undefined') ? event.keyCode : event.which;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (listenForShiftKey(event) && keyCode === 9)`
you are not passing event to function `listenForShiftKey()`

Comment: Sorry I was trying with or without it. In both cases it still doesn't work.

Comment: because window.event is undefined in firefox and e also undefined, so evt will undefined only.

Comment: Is there a way to capture shift pression in Firefox?

Comment: `evt.shiftKey` will work for all browser, check for charCode instead of keyCode i guess... bdw i am not able to capture shift+tab in chrome, it going to another tab right